# linq summing values by two different ranges

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a linq statement for a pivottable that sums values based on date range which is in a 3 month period and an interval range. For example,

```
value        Date               Interval
 10        02-14-2020             33
 23        01-10-2020             34
 15        03-24-2020             10
 69        06-20-2020             65 
 52        08-15-2020             63
 34        11-20-2020            100  
 42        12-20-2020             97
```

my date range would be every 3 months in a year and interval range would would be every 5 (30,35,40,45...). So what I am trying to get the out to be

output:

```
  33 (10+23) for range 1/1/2020 to 3/31/2020 and interval 30-35
  15 for range 1/1/2020 to 3/31/2020 and interval 5 - 10
  81 for range 4/1/2020 to 6/30/2020 and interval 60-65
  76 for range 10/1/2020 to 12/31/2020 and interval 95-100


  List<sm> sm = new List<sm>() {
            new sm { value = 10, date = Convert.ToDateTime("02 - 14 - 2020") , Interval = 33 },
            new sm { value = 23, date = Convert.ToDateTime("01 - 10 - 2020") , Interval = 34 },
            new sm { value = 15, date = Convert.ToDateTime("03 - 24 - 2020") , Interval = 10 },
            new sm { value = 69, date = Convert.ToDateTime("06 - 20 - 2020") , Interval = 65 },
            new sm { value = 52, date = Convert.ToDateTime("08 - 15 - 2020") , Interval = 63 },
            new sm { value = 34, date = Convert.ToDateTime("11 - 20 - 2020") , Interval = 100 },
            new sm { value = 42, date = Convert.ToDateTime("12 - 20 - 2020") , Interval = 97 },
        };
```

not sure how to do this, do I use a group by and check for the date and interval range in the group by or would i just need to do it in the where clause. do I need to have the interval ranges and date ranges in separate lists as well to check against?

Comment: for range 1/1/2020 to 3/31/2020 and interval 30-35, sum you say is 33 = 10 + 23. But why? Isn't it 10 + 23 + 15 = 48?

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan `15` has an interval of `10`, so it's not included.

Comment: Oh ok, but what about the sum for range 1/1/2020 to 3/31/2020 and interval 0-5? 0 because both ranges must match?

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan no im going to sum up values in the date range and in the interval range so 2 rows fall into that category then they will be summed up

Comment: Your intervals overlap - if you have intervals from `5-10` and `10-15`, then an item with interval `10` will be in both. Shouldn't they be `0-4`, `5-9`, `10-14`, etc. ?

Comment: @AC25 so it should be: for range 1/1/2020 to 3/31/2020 **OR** (not and) interval 30-35. right?

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan it should be and

Comment: @RufusL yeah that is correct I was just tryiing to put up a sample up to get a linq statement

Comment: @AC25 but (referring to my last question) there are values that match the date range but not the interval, thus you are using the "or" case. If that's what you want then your first example should be 48 because 3rd sample matches date but not interval

Comment: You should be able to `.GroupBy(r => new{ Quarter = r.date.Month/3, ...`

Comment: How do you come up with `81 for range 4/1/2020 to 6/30/2020 and interval 60-65`?

Comment: @RufusL should it be AND or OR isn't clear. that answer would make sense if the question used OR. But it wants AND so idk

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan I don't see any values with that date/interval that could be summed to equal `81`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick implementation of sm class and the linq statement in static GetSum method:

```
class sm
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public bool InDateRange ( DateTime start, DateTime end ) => start <= Date && Date <= end;
    public bool InIntervalRange ( int start, int end ) => start <= Interval && Interval <= end;

    public static int GetSum ( IEnumerable<sm> sms, int intervalStart, int intervalEnd, DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd ) => sms
        .Where ( sm => sm.InDateRange ( dateStart, dateEnd ) && sm.InIntervalRange ( intervalStart, intervalEnd ) )
        .Sum ( sm => sm.value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made one change to your intervals, so that they don't overlap. The are `0-4, 5-9, 10-14`, etc.

One way to solve the problem you've described is to first write a class that represents a result (has a date range, an interval range, and a value):

```
public class Result
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int IntervalStart { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; } = 4;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Value} for range {StartDate.ToShortDateString()} to " +
            $"{EndDate.ToShortDateString()} and interval " + 
            $"{IntervalStart}-{IntervalStart + Interval}";
    }
}
```

And then iterate over the items, adding each item either to an existing result (that meets the date/interval requirements) or as a new result:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Create a list of sample items
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item {Value = 10, Date = DateTime.Parse("02/14/2020"), Interval = 33},
        new Item {Value = 23, Date = DateTime.Parse("01/10/2020"), Interval = 34},
        new Item {Value = 15, Date = DateTime.Parse("03/24/2020"), Interval = 10},
        new Item {Value = 69, Date = DateTime.Parse("06/20/2020"), Interval = 65},
        new Item {Value = 52, Date = DateTime.Parse("08/15/2020"), Interval = 63},
        new Item {Value = 34, Date = DateTime.Parse("11/20/2020"), Interval = 100},
        new Item {Value = 42, Date = DateTime.Parse("12/20/2020"), Interval = 97},
    };

    var results = new List<Result>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var interval = item.Interval / 10 * 10 + (item.Interval % 10 < 5 ? 0 : 5);

        // Try to find a result that this item can be added to
        var match = results.FirstOrDefault(r =>
            r.IntervalStart <= item.Interval &&
            r.IntervalStart + r.Interval >= item.Interval &&
            r.StartDate <= item.Date &&
            r.EndDate >= item.Date);

        // No existing result found, so create a new one for this item
        if (match == null)
        {
            var month = item.Date.Month / 4 * 3 + 1;
            var startDate = new DateTime(item.Date.Year, month, 1);
            var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1);

            results.Add(new Result
            {
                StartDate = startDate,
                EndDate = endDate,
                IntervalStart = interval,
                Value = item.Value
            });
        }
        else
        {
            match.Value += item.Value;
        }
    }

    results.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]